# Cauchy criterion and null sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $(a_n)_{ n\in\mathbb N}$ a decreasing sequence of positive real numbers. Show that:

if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{a_n}$ converges prove that $n\cdot{a_n}$ is a null sequence

I know that I should use Cauchy's criterion but I don't know how to do the proof. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Write, for $n>m$,
$$
(n-m)a_n=\sum_{k=m+1}^n a_n\stackrel{(1)}\le\sum_{k=m+1}^na_k
$$
where in (1) we use the fact that $\{a_n\}$ is a decreasing sequence. Therefore we have, whenever $n>m$,
$$
0\le na_n= ma_n +\sum_{k=m+1}^na_k .
$$
By the Cauchy criterion we can choose $m$ large enough to make the second term on the RHS as small as we please. Given such an $m$, we can choose $n$ large enough to make the first term on the RHS as small as we please, since $a_n\to0$.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Cauchy's criterion.  However, I find that it is more intuitive to note that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} n \,a_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{1/n}
$$
and that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/n$ is a divergent series.

Comment: But how to you know this limit exists at all?  You'll need to use the assumption that $a_n$ decreases as $n$ increases.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I know it's using a cannon, but what do you think about the following argument to show the existence without assuming that $a_n$ decreases? Let $b_n$ be an shuffling of the  series $a_n$ so that is monotonically decreasing. Then $\lim n b_n = 0$. Then we show that $\lim na_n = \lim nb_n \implies \lim n(a_n - b_n) = 0$ which is true because $\sum( a_n - b_n) = 0 $ is convergent (because $a_n$ is absolutely convergent, we can change the order of the elements in the sum)

Comment: @Ant : I'm going to hazard a guess about what you meant.  You know $\sum(a_n-b_n)=0$; from that you're deducing that $\lim n(a_n-b_n)=0$, and from that you're deducing $\lim na_n=\lim nb_n$.  That would mean your $\Longrightarrow$ should have said $\Longleftarrow$ instead.  However, the fact that $\lim(c_n-d_n)=0$ doesn't necessarily imply that $\lim c_n=\lim d_n$, since in some cases $\lim(c_n-d_n)=0$ when $\lim c_n$ and $\lim d_n$ do not exist. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy You nailed the problem. Thank you for the clarification, I had overlooked that :-)